# Table and figure side by side in two column layout without space below

Tags: tables, floats, two-column

This is kind of a strange requirement I suppose. I have a table and a figure and I want them to be side by side on top of a page, on the same page, while the table is in the left column and the figure is in the right one.

I know I could put them inside a box or a minipage but the figure is much taller than the table and thus there would be wasted space under the table.

I also heard of the `floatrow` package but it has the limitation that the two objects need to be of the same type (a table and a figure).

Is there a way to do this or am I doomed to balance the text manually before the final revision?

Comment: `Floatrow` can mix tables and figures. The difficulty might come from the  two-column layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution. we set  `\setcounter{topnumber}{1}` and then restore its value

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\edef\mttopnumber{\arabic{topnumber}}
\setcounter{topnumber}{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tp]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
12 & 13 \\ 
\hline 
10 & 11 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[tp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
\caption{Nice figure}
\end{figure}
\setcounter{topnumber}{\mttopnumber}
\lipsum
\begin{table}[tp]
\centering
\caption{A table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
12 & 13 \\ 
\hline 
10 & 11 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{figure}[tp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image}
\caption{Nice figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, nice, I already experimented with this but didnt know it could be changed in the middle of the document. I think the 3rd line of your script should be `\redef`? Also this relies on the image and the table being set on the same page, correct? There is nothing preventing the table to appear at one page and the figure at the next, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @theswine you're right, I can't see any good way to do this, but you can move (change the place of) the figure and table in the input to ensure that. for your first question no `\mttopnumber` is new command that only save the default value of `topnumber`.

Answer (score 4):

A weird approach with a `figure*` environment which spans both columns and nested tabular environments to get the alignment.

The filling depends on the size of the table and the image of course. (the `\hline`s are just for checking, not for real output)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}


\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[ht!]
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{*{2}X}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{p{\linewidth}}
      \centering
      \begin{tabular}[c]{lllll}
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
        Here & comes & the & real & table \tabularnewline
      \end{tabular}
    \end{tabular} &
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}[c]{c}
      \includegraphics{example-a} 
    \end{tabular} \tabularnewline
    \captionof{table}{A table} &
    \captionof{figure}{A figure} \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{figure*}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice but does not solve my problem. There will be quite a lot of space wasted. Imagine the table only has two rows - they will be centered on that figure with empty space on top and bottom.

Comment: Well, you need something like `wrapfigure` then