# how to align table and figure side by side

Tags: tables

i am using the ieee 2 column format on overleaf. I have a table and figure I want to place them side by side like this figure.
[image]

I tried this code but its not working for me due to errors [Table and figure side by side in two column layout without space below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272597/table-and-figure-side-by-side-in-two-column-layout-without-space-below)

but how can i modify my this code

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\tiny \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
ooooooooo& bbbbbb 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccvvvvvv} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccccccc}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}  
 & & \makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (vvvvvvv)}  &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv \\ (vvvvvvvv)} \\




\midrule
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbb  &fff &fffffffff   &fffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffff &  fffffff8 &fff  &fffffffffffff  & ff &fffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffffff & ffffffffff     &fff &ffffffffff   & ffff &ffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  & fffff &fff &fffffffffffff  &fff &fffffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffff     &fff &ffffffffffff4  &ffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & fffffff &fffffff &fffffffff  &ffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  &  ffffffff &fff &ffff   &fffffffffffff& ff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffffff &8fffff &ffffffffffff  &ffff& fffffffffffff\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=5cm]{Fig.png}
  \caption{(a) Avvvvvvvvv (b) bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `\captionof` is now standard LaTeX, or at least in IEEEtran.  Aligning centers or bottoms is easy (use [c] or [b] in the minipages) but aligning the tops requires `\raisebox{-\height}{...}`.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}% redundant
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}% or figure*
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\tiny \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\centering
\captionof{table}{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
ooooooooo& bbbbbb 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccvvvvvv} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccccccc}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}  
 & & \makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (vvvvvvv)}  &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv \\ (vvvvvvvv)} \\




\midrule
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbb  &fff &fffffffff   &fffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffff &  fffffff8 &fff  &fffffffffffff  & ff &fffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffffff & ffffffffff     &fff &ffffffffff   & ffff &ffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  & fffff &fff &fffffffffffff  &fff &fffffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffff     &fff &ffffffffffff4  &ffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & fffffff &fffffff &fffffffff  &ffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  &  ffffffff &fff &ffff   &fffffffffffff& ff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffffff &8fffff &ffffffffffff  &ffff& fffffffffffff\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}\hfill% no blank line here
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{(a) Avvvvvvvvv (b) bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\end{minipage}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain what you want with the `subfloatrow` environment, from the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\usepackage{subcaption, floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\begin{subfloatrow}[2]
\CenterFloatBoxes
\ttabbox{\caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}\label{tbl}}
{\tiny \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
ooooooooo& bbbbbb
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccvvvvvv}
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccccccc}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
 & & \makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (vvvvvvv)} &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv \\ (vvvvvvvv)} \\
\midrule
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbb &fff &fffffffff &fffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffff & fffffff8 &fff &fffffffffffff & ff &fffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffffff & ffffffffff &fff &ffffffffff & ffff &ffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & fffff &fff &fffffffffffff &fff &fffffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff & ffffffff &fff &ffffffffffff4 &ffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & fffffff &fffffff &fffffffff &ffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & ffffffff &fff &ffff &fffffffffffff& ff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff & ffffffffff &8fffff &ffffffffffff &ffff& fffffffffffff\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\killfloatstyle
\hskip 6em
\ffigbox [\FBwidth]{\raggedleft\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{Nightmare_Fussli}}
 { \caption{Johann-Heinrich Füssli: Nightmare}\label{fig}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Imran: Thank you for the edit!

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: how can i remove that a) and b ) a should be table its not a &  b

Comment: I don't understand – your own code contains an (a) and a (b). It should be  possible to obtain Table (a) and Figure (b) with the `caption` package.